# Meaning of the return value of OnTouchEventListener

Tags: android

Why does that mean by `return false` in `OnTouchEventListener`. What difference does it make if we change it to `return true`?

I found that "True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise."
But I am not getting what does that mean by "consumed the event"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I found that "True if the listener has consumed the event, false
>   otherwise." But I am not getting what does that mean by "consumed the
>   event"?

Consuming the event means that its listener won't pass this event to further listeners, because this particular listener consumed it.

So, what are those further listeners, they can be one or more listeners; for instance when you **tap** a view, then the `onTouch()` callback method of the `OnTouchEventListener` of this particular view is triggered, and if you return `true`, then this listener consumes the event, so the next listener(s) callbacks won't be triggered; which is in our case the `onClick()` callback of the `OnClickListener` of this particular view that won't be called.

**More Illustration:**

Assume you've a button, and you registered below event listeners for it.

```
    Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "Touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true; // Consumes the event
        }
    });

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Now when you tap that button, only the **Touched** toast will be shown, and not the **Clicked** toast, because you return `true` from `onTouch()`

If you return `false` from `onTouch()`, then both **Touched** and **Clicked** will be shown.

The same applies for `View.OnLongClickListener`

Answer (score 1):

when we click a button, an event object is passed into the event handler. For buttons it is "onClickListener" for example.

When the event is passed into the function, you have 2 options, Either to check the event and do some action. Example, if the event was a "keyPress" , you can check if the key pressed was digit or alphabet and perform some meaningful business logic. That is called consuming the event. If you do absolutely nothing with the event, that means that the event was passed to you but you did not consume it. So by default it's false. But you can set it to true, which means "I dont care about the event itself, I dont want to do any computation on it, just mark it as read and make the button click". So in that case we just type in true, as to indicate that we consumed the event, while actually we did not, which is fine.

Make sense ? I tried to break it down as I understand event myself