# What to do with the boolean return of the OnTouchListener (MapView)?

Tags: android-studio, android-mapview

I'm working on an app that uses a `MapView` instance called `map`. At a certain point I want to know if the map has been touched. To that purpose Android Studio generated this `boolean return` callback method (see below) for the `OnTouchListener`.

```
MapView map;    
map = findViewById(R.id.view_map);     
map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch (View v) {
                 return false;
      }
});
```

As you can see, unlike in a simple `OnClickListener`, you are apparently not free to write the method that should follow a touch event. That method appears to be fixed at `return false`. You **cannot** change it to e.g. a `void` method.

**What is the purpose of that return? To where/what will `false`  be returned?** Is it perhaps stored in the object `map`, as a `field` of the `MapView class`? If I knew, I could initialize that field/variable to `true`, wait for the `OnTouchListener` to change it to `false`, and then use that information elsewhere in the app (e.g. to suspend the app's instruction to continuously center the map on the current GPS position).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of the return value of OnTouchEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296414/meaning-of-the-return-value-of-ontoucheventlistener)